# PHP Where throw Exceptions

Tags: php, exception

Firstly sorry for my English...

I have a question about throwing exceptions; please see this code:

**First**

```
class SimpleClass
{
    public function mainFn()
    {
        $this->notTheMainFn1();
        $this->notTheMainFn2();
    }

    private function notTheMainFn1()
    {
        // fn returns value or throw Exception
    }

    private function notTheMainFn2()
    {
        // fn returns value or throw Exception
    }
}
```

**Second**

```
class SimpleClass2
{
    public function mainFn()
    {
        if ($this->notTheMainFn() === false) {
            throw new Exception('some error');
        }
    }

    private function notTheMainFn()
    {
        // fn returns value or false if error
    }
}
```

Which way is better? Is better to return false or null in depend methods and check in the main method and throw Exception if needed?

Comment: throw the exception at the highest possible level ( the service layer ). the data access layer should only contain

Comment: Assuming mainFn is your entry point then I'd use a try/catch block in mainFn() and have the other 2 functions to throw the exceptions you're planning to throw.

Comment: In our applications, we prefer to use exceptions for errors. Return value types should be consistent. For example, returning false from a method due to an error that should normally return an array just seems a little backwards to me.